# How to create Spring Boot REST service "type: POST"?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, post

I'm a beginner in spring boot and I'm trying to create REST endpoint that's adding two numbers (type: POST) so can anyone help me with that and tell me where is the problems in my code??

```
package demo.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import demo.service.ServiceAdding;

@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceAdding ServiceAdding;

    @RequestMapping(value="/getNumbers", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ServiceAdding getNumbers() {

        ServiceAdding.setNumber1(1);
        ServiceAdding.setNumber2(3);

        return ServiceAdding;

    }

        @RequestMapping(value="/postNumbers", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public int postNumbers (@RequestBody final ServiceAdding ServiceAdding ) {

            int sum = ServiceAdding.getNumber1() + ServiceAdding.getNumber2();
            return sum;
        }




    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: that's the response of localhost

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Comment: And what URL exactly do you call? Please add all relevant information to your question (what actions you do, what result you get, what result you expect)?

Comment: I'm calling this liknk http://localhost:8080/postNumbers  and I am feeling that I have something wrong in my code but as I told before I'm a beginner and I can't catch the problem ... I am trying to add just two digits and showing the result in the browser

Comment: and how exactly are you calling it? What client do you use and how exactly do you configure it? And does getNumbers work, if you call that endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Try using @PostMapping instead of @RequestMapping

```
    @PostMapping(value = "postNumbers")
    public int postNumbers(...){
      ...
    }
```

Comment: You must not be performing a POST request. See @Jim M. 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

what errors are you getting?

Also try adding a value to the restController maybe?

`@RestController(value="api/v1")`

`@RequestMapping(value = "/getNumbers, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")`

You can also use `@GetMapping, @PostMapping` etc

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not performing a POST request. How do you load that URL?

You need to have either:

1. Webpage that has a FORM that does a POST
2. Use a tool like [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/) (or similar tool) to submit the post request.

Answer (score 0):

The correct one should be like below :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DemoController {

... other codes

    @RequestMapping(value="/postNumbers", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public int postNumbers (@RequestBody SumNumbersRequest sumNumbersRequest) 
    {

        int sum = sumNumbersRequest.getNumber1() + sumNumbersRequest.getNumber2();
        return sum;
    }
}

@Data // from Lombok for getter setter
class SumNumbersRequest {
    private int number1;
    private int number2;
}
```

And you should post json request to url localhost:8080/api/postNumber as below with Content-Type : application/json :

```
{
   "number1":5,
   "number2":15
}
```